# New Relic Manual time reporting

Tags: javascript, analytics, newrelic

**What i would like to achive:**

I would like to send the time took to make my page fully interactive

**Description:**

I use requirejs as dependency manager for my javascript, so basically i would like to send the time took untill my page script was fully excuted

**Example:**

Total time untill page is fully interactive = new Date().getTime() - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible to report this value to New Relic separately from the other page load time values. I'd contact [New Relic support](https://support.newrelic.com) for more information.